# Formula Query Multiple Columns with Filter in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have two sheets in data google sheet, let's both named is sheet 1 and sheet 2. In sheet 1, I have four columns as below:

[image]

And in sheet 2, I have multiple columns and row in below:

[image]

If I want to filter sheet 1 based column Lot No, example the Lot No is 01/09/2023, 02/09/2023, and 04/09/2023. If i paste the Lot No to column Lot 1, Lot 2, and Lot 3 (sheet 2), then on sheet 2 it will output the column as follows:

[image]

Does anyone know the formula to solve this problem on row Sample Number (S1)?

Comment: `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question.` Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Would you please edit your question to include data as text tables. There are a number of ways to do this: one option is to use the free, online service at [www.tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do it with something like this, in cell A4 (ensuring there is nothing else in row 4):

```
=index({"Sample Number (S1)",
iferror(if(B2:2<>"",
vlookup(B2:2,sort({Sheet1!$D:$D,Row(Sheet1!$D:$D)-1},2,1),2,0)
&"-"&
vlookup(B2:2,sort({Sheet1!$D:$D,Row(Sheet1!$D:$D)-1},2,0),2,0)
,),)})
```

If it helps, I'll add an explanation.

[image]